# Scraping certain Index

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-irkernel

I am scraping the website to gather the entire price details on a certain website. I am using Jupyter Notebook as my tool and I have have the following issues.

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


# This section is for Windows computer
s = Service('C:/Users/Owner/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/win32/106.0.5249.61/chromedriver')
chromeOptions = Options()
chromeOptions.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=chromeOptions)


# Create the url pattern for search in home depot web page
base_url = "https://www.homedepot.com/s/mosaic%20title?Nao=360"
url = f"{base_url}"



html = driver.page_source
soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
company_detail = soup.find_all("div", class_="browse-search__pod col__12-12 col__6-12--xs col__4-12--sm col__3-12--md col__3-12--lg")


span_price = [spanList.find("div",class_="price").find_all("span") for spanList in company_detail]
retail_price = [float(".".join([each[1].text,each[2].text])) for each in span_price]
```

**Plan:** I have a line of code that finds the entire price in the webiste and extracts the following information based in Index Value.

```
[<span class="price__format">$</span>, <span>27</span>, <span class="price__format">18</span>]
```

| Index | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Index(0) | $ |
| Index(1) | 27 |
| Index(2) | 18 |

**Issue:**  The code breaks when there's an item being sold by the cents value only and it's a different structure.

```
[<span class="price-format__main-price">33</span>, <span class="price__format">¢</span>]
```

| Index | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Index(0) | 33 |
| Index(1) | ¢ |
| Index(2) |  |

**Question:**  Is there a way to tell Python that if Index(0) = $ Then extract Index(1) & Index(2), if not extract Index(0) only?

**Goal:** To extract everything on the website, and have it as a table.

| List |
| --- |
| 0.33 |
| 27.18 |
| 99.99 |

I tried using different If statement but sadly I failed. Maybe I'm doing it wrong.

11/08/2022 - UPDATE

I might have a solution to fix this, not sure if this is the right way, maybe you guys can give me some adivce? I am trying to makea code where if it finds string '$' then to run the code, else run a different code to retrieve that given string. Add a loop, +1, so it can run for the next line of code.

```
retail_price1 = (span_price[0])
print(retail_price1)
```

```
[<span class="price-format__main-price">33</span>, <span class="price__format">¢</span>]
```

```
retail_price1 = (span_price[1])
print(retail_price1)
```

```
[<span class="price__format">$</span>, <span>27</span>, <span class="price__format">18</span>]
```

Comment: Sorry, I just realized the title error. I am scraping the web.

Comment: I'd bet 90% of the scraping posts make the same spelling errors.

Comment: Haha, thank you for that note, makes me feel better. If I miss anything else, let me know